# DEVISE - successful message when ask for a new password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I'm using the Devise gem and I just would like to show a successful message when someone ask for a new password (if forgotten). Currently, when submitted, the button redirects to sign_in without any message.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the flash and trying to work out how Devise does it's thing (not for the faint-hearted) by extending its controllers, how about checking the referrer, and displaying a message in the view if it matches your 'remind me of my password' path?

In the view:

```
<% if request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] == "/give/me/a/new/password" %>
  <h2>Your password stuff is all good now.</h2>
<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry i'm new on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

flash[:success] = "Something Something"

Comment: This will require customization on the devise controllers. Please post that code if you have it.

Comment: Ok thanks ! But which controller do I have to override ? passwords_controller ? I'm quite lost :/

Answer (score 0):

Devise rolls out it's own alert messages (and they can be edited in the `config/locales/devise.en.yml` and written for other languages), you just need to catch them.

One way is to add a `layout/_messages` partial:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name %>">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and render it in `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
```

*This has the benefit of catching all (devise and other) messages and playing nicely with bootstrap alert classes (if you use were using bootstrap).*

.

Or if you are using [slim](http://slim-lang.com/):

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  - if msg.is_a?(String)
    div class="alert alert-#{name}"
      a class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
        | &#215;
      = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"

= render 'layouts/messages'
```

.

Devise uses [the rails standard `:notice` rather than `:success`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/805) but a you can [add the success (green) styling](https://github.com/smidig/conference-app/issues/28) to your css/scss (e.g. to `bootstrap_and_overriders.css.scss`):

```
.alert-alert {
  @extend .alert-error
}
.alert-notice {
  @extend .alert-success
}
```